# main.cpp|83|undefined reference to `avag(double, double, int, double)'|

Tags: c++, function, pointers, header

i have stupid issue with pointers and function >:(

main.cpp|83|undefined reference to `avag(double, double, int, double)'|

Please help

i have issue with my avarage function with pointers

main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mojafunkcja.h"

using namespace std;

double tab[0];
int naCo, CoChceszRobic;
double cm, M, Km, Cl, Mi, Jd, St;

int main(){

    cout<<"Co chcesz robic?: 1. Zamiana jednostek \n 2. Min/Max/Avg z tablicy ORAZ SORTOWANIE \n 3. "<<endl;
    cin>>CoChceszRobic;
    if(CoChceszRobic==1)
    {
    cout<<"Witaj! Podaj jaka jednostke chcesz zamienic:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Centymetry na Cale \n 2. Metry  na Stopki \n 3. Kilometry na Mile \n 4. Cale na Centymetry  \n 5. Stopy na metry \n 6. Mile na Kilometry \n 7. Jardy na Kilometry"<<endl;
    cin>>naCo;
    if(naCo==1)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj cm: ";
        cin>>cm;
        cout<<cm<<" cm ma "<<centymetryNaCale(cm)<<" cali";
    }
    if(naCo==2)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj M: ";
        cin>>M;
        cout<<M<<" M ma "<<metryNaStopy(M)<<" Stop(y)";
    }
    if(naCo==3)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj Km: ";
        cin>>Km;
        cout<<Km<<" Km ma "<<kilometryNaMile(Km)<<" Mil(i)";;
    }
    if(naCo==4)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj Cale: ";
        cin>>Cl;
        cout<<Cl<<" cali ma "<<caleNaCentymetry(Cl)<<" Centymetrow";
    }
    if(naCo==5)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj Stopy: ";
        cin>>St;
        cout<<St<<" Stop(y) ma "<<stopyNaMetry(St)<<" Metrow(y)";
    }
    if(naCo==6)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj Mile: ";
        cin>>Mi;
        cout<<Mi<<" Mil ma "<<MileNaKilometry(Mi)<<" Kilometrow(y)";;
    }
    if(naCo==7)
    {
        cout<<"Podaj Jardy: ";
        cin>>Jd;
        cout<<Jd<<" Jard ow ma "<<jardyNaKilometry(Jd)<<" Kilometrow(y)";;
    }
    if(naCo>7 || naCo<1){
        cout<<"Podales zla wartosc :( "<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        main();
    }
    }
    if(CoChceszRobic==2)
    {
        int JakaDuza=1;
        double avg=0;
        double sum=0;
        double tab[JakaDuza];
        double *wsk;
        wsk=tab;
        cout<<"Jaka duza ma byc tablica? ";
        cin>>JakaDuza;
        for(int i=0; i<JakaDuza; i++)
        {
            cout<<i+1<<". ";
            cin>>*(wsk+i);;
            sum+=tab[i];
        }
        cout<<avag(avg,sum,JakaDuza,*wsk); <<<<<<<<<ISSUE IS HERE!!!

    }
}
```

my mojafunkcja.h

```
    double centymetryNaCale(double);
    double metryNaStopy(double);
    double kilometryNaMile(double);
    double caleNaCentymetry(double);
    double stopyNaMetry(double);
    double MileNaKilometry(double);
    double jardyNaKilometry(double);
    double avag(double,double,int,double);
```

my mojafunkcja.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mojafunkcja.h"

using namespace std;

double centymetryNaCale(double centy)
{
    return centy/2.54;
}

double metryNaStopy(double metry)
{
    return metry*3.2808;
}
double kilometryNaMile(double Kilo)
{
    return Kilo*0.6213;
}
double caleNaCentymetry(double cale)
{
    return cale*2.54;
}

double stopyNaMetry(double stop)
{
    return stop/3.2808;
}
double MileNaKilometry(double Kilo)
{
    return Kilo/0.621371192;
}
double jardyNaKilometry(double Kilo)
{
    return Kilo*1093.6;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double avag(double avg, double sum, int n, double wsk[]){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+= wsk[i];
    }
    avg=sum/n;
    return avg;
    }
```

I don't know how to use pointers. You can ignore all doubles with cale, stopy etc. it is not making any issues with code but everything under ////////// does

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you so much for help man i like you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

`double avag(double avg, double sum, int n, double wsk[])` is not the same as `double avag(double,double,int,double);` so your declaration does not match the implementation.

In `mojafunkcja.h`, change the declaration of `avag` to:

```
double avag(double avg, double sum, int n, double wsk[]);
```

and don't dereference `wsk` in the call to `avag`:

```cpp
std::cout << avag(avg, sum, JakaDuza, wsk) << '\n';
```